# R - Customize plot output by MatchIt package

Tags: r, graphics

How can you customize a plot generated from a package implementing its own `plot` method? Specifically in the case of `plot.Matchit`:

```
plot(match, type = "hist")
```

I would like to change `Raw Treated`, `Raw Control`, `Matched Treated`, and `Matched Control` to my own custom labels.

[image: match]

Comment: not possible currently, those labels are [hard-coded](https://github.com/kosukeimai/MatchIt/blob/master/R/hist.pscore.R#L30:L43), and if you use `plot(..., main = )`, all plots will have the same title. it's pretty silly to have a condition only based on whether `main` was given or not, this could easily be fixed to allow custom user titles

Comment: That's so annoying. Why would they do that knowing people would want to use these plots in publications? Guess I'll bust out Microsoft Paint...

Answer (score 1):

You can follow `MatchIt:::plot.matchit` to the plotting function which is eventually used, in your case it looks to be `MatchIt:::hist.pscore`. You can hijack this independently, but if you change your matching algorithm, it may change the plotting function.

```
library('MatchIt')
m <- matchit(treat ~ re74 + re75 + educ + black + hispan + age,
             data = lalonde, method = "nearest")
plot(m, type = 'hist')

## original / plot(m)
hist.pscore(m)
```

[image]

```
hist.pscore(m, main = c('Pre-matching\nExperimental', 'Matched - Experimental',
                        'Pre-matching\nControl', 'Matched - Control'))
```

[image]

```
hist.pscore <- function(x, numdraws = 5000, xlab = "Propensity Score",
                        main = NULL, freq = FALSE, xlim = NULL, type, ...) {
  main <- rep(main, 4)
  `%||%` <- function(x, y) if (is.null(x)) y else x
  treat <- x$treat
  pscore <- x$distance
  weights <- x$weights
  matched <- weights!=0
  q.cut <- x$q.cut
  cwt <- sqrt(weights)
  ratio <- x$call$ratio
  if (is.null(ratio))
    ratio <- 1
  
  ## For full or ratio matching, sample numdraws observations using the weights
  if (identical(x$call$method, "full") | (ratio != 1)) {
    pscore.treated.matched <- sample(names(treat)[treat == 1],
                                     numdraws / 2, replace = TRUE,
                                     prob = x$weights[treat == 1])
    pscore.treated.matched <- pscore[pscore.treated.matched]
    pscore.control.matched <- sample(names(treat)[treat == 0],
                                     numdraws / 2, replace = TRUE,
                                     prob = x$weights[treat == 0])
    pscore.control.matched <- pscore[pscore.control.matched]
  } else {
    pscore.treated.matched <- pscore[treat == 1 & weights != 0]
    pscore.control.matched <- pscore[treat == 0 & weights != 0]
  }
  par_prior <- par(mfrow = c(2, 2)) ## Store prior par config before changing
  on.exit(par(par_prior))
  
  if (!is.null(xlim))
    warning("xlim may not be user specified. xlim returned to default.")
  
  xlim <- range(na.omit(pscore))
  
  hist(pscore[treat == 1], xlim = xlim, xlab = xlab, freq = freq,
       main = main[1] %||% "Raw Treated", ...)
  hist(pscore.treated.matched, xlim = xlim, xlab = xlab, freq = freq,
       main = main[2] %||% "Matched Treated", ...)
  if(!is.null(q.cut))
    abline(v = q.cut, col = "grey", lty = 1)
  
  hist(pscore[treat == 0], xlim = xlim, xlab = xlab, freq = freq,
       main = main[3] %||% "Raw Control", ...)
  hist(pscore.control.matched, xlim = xlim, xlab = xlab, freq = freq,
       main = main[4] %||% "Matched Control", ...)
  if (!is.null(q.cut))
    abline(v = q.cut, col = "grey",lty = 1)
}
```